# HTML5 and gaming practices

Tags: html5, game-development, app

I am trying to build an app with HTML5.

Is there a certain syntax to follow when making objects for games?
Anyone tried that and what are good practices to follow?

Comment: you might be interested in checking http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ out ;)

Comment: I agree with @Songo. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are two main options: 
a) using canvas and raycasting b) using game engine to achieve the 3D effect in HTML5.

Have a look at the following cool tutorials and posts:

1. [Creating pseudo 3D games with HTML 5 canvas and raycasting](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/creating-pseudo-3d-games-with-html-5-can-1/)
2. [How to Create an HTML5 3D Engine](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-create-an-html5-3d-engine/)
3. [Canvas tutorials](http://www.canvasdemos.com/type/tutorials/)
4. [HTML5 ROCKS - POSTS & TUTORIALS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/)

Comment: no problem, sometimes we all have that feeling